# Make Qt Creator generate proper .pro files for including g++ static libraries on Windows

Tags: g++, qt-creator, static-linking, qmake

I've had problems with creating and linking static libraries in Qt Creator on Windows 7 when using mingw g++. I found one solution by manually hacking the auto generated files but I don't like it.

Let's say you have a subdirs project containing an application subproject and a library subproject as follows.

`parent.pro`

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS += \
    utilities \
    program
```

`utilities.pro`

```
CONFIG += staticlib
TARGET = utilities
TEMPLATE = lib
HEADERS += ...
SOURCES += ...
```

`program.pro`

```
TEMPLATE = app
INCLUDEPATH += ../utilities/
HEADERS += ...
SOURCES += ...
```

If you use the Qt Creator built in feature to add the internal library to the application it generates the following lines in the application's `.pro` file:

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += \
    -L$$OUT_PWD/../utilities/release/ -lutilities
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += \
    -L$$OUT_PWD/../utilities/debug/ -lutilities
else:symbian: LIBS += \
    -lutilities
else:unix: LIBS += \
    -L$$OUT_PWD/../utilities/ -lutilities

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../utilities
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../utilities

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += \
    $$OUT_PWD/../utilities/release/utilities.lib
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += \
    $$OUT_PWD/../utilities/debug/utilities.lib
else:unix:!symbian: PRE_TARGETDEPS += \
    $$OUT_PWD/../utilities/libutilities.a
```

This is very useful except it seems to assume names which don't tie up with the automatically generated ones. My hack is to go through and change the last paragraph to...

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += \
    $$OUT_PWD/../utils/release/libutils.a
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += \
    $$OUT_PWD/../utils/debug/libutils.a
else:unix:!symbian: PRE_TARGETDEPS += \
    $$OUT_PWD/../utils/libutils.a
```

...so it matches the library names produced by g++.

Is there a single setting/definition which I could add to the library or application .pro files so that the names end up matching (and preferably appropriate to the tool chain being used)? Performing this step is a frequent irritation.

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember, things like how the libraries are names is part of the QMAKESPEC used. For MingW is should be "win32-g++".

In Qt Creator, you can change the QMakeSpec indirectly through the projects setting by choosing the "Tool chain."

Comment: Yep: `qmake.exe F:\ProjectName\ProjectName.pro -r -spec win32-g++ ...` The issue isn't the name of the library output by g++ being wrong. It's the name as Qt Creator automatically populates the .pro with when using the 'add internal library' feature.